# Best way convert text with '&' into the variables

Tags: php, arrays, text, variables

I've got this text

"?foo=bar&foobar=barfoo"

what is the best way to convert this text to variables? Like this:

```
<?php
echo $q['foo']; //bar
echo $q['foobar']; //barfoo
?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

see http://docs.php.net/parse_str and http://docs.php.net/parse_url

```
$s = "?foo=bar&foobar=barfoo";
parse_str(parse_url($s, PHP_URL_QUERY), $q);
var_dump($q);
```

prints

```
array(2) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  ["foobar"]=>
  string(6) "barfoo"
}
```

edit: If you know the string always has the form **?**x=y... you might want to skip parse_url() and use [substr()](http://docs.php.net/substr) instead.
edit2: Keep in mind that the behavior of parse_str() depends on the value of [arg_separator.input](http://docs.php.net/ini.core#ini.arg-separator.input). Should you set it (for whatever reason) to something like '!' parse_string() will return NULL for your input string.
e.g.

```
ini_set('arg_separator.input', '!');
$s = "foo=bar&foobar=barfoo";
var_dump(parse_str($s));
```

prints `NULL`. But ...that would be a rather odd setting.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a url so if you get it from a url source they should be automatically in $_GET['foo'] and $_GET['bar'] but if it's just a text string, you can do this:

```
$string = "?foo=bar&foobar=barfoo";
$string = str_replace('?', '', $string);
$params = explode('&', $string);

foreach($params as $key=>$value)
{
    $data = explode('=', $value);
    $_GET[$data[0]] = $data[1];
}
```

And all of your vars will be in $_GET array.